# Why isn't \\ or \newline working?

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking, amsmath, line-spacing

I can't figure out why neither of these commands (`\\` or `\newline`) will work to start a new line for all of my equations.

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\begin{document}
\maketitle % showing both title and author, plus and automatic date
Consider the conic section
\begin{equation}

Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0.

\end{equation}
If $B\neq0$, then to eliminate the xy term, we rotate the axes through an acute angle $\theta$ where 
\begin{equation}

\cot(2\theta)=\frac{A-C}{B}.

\end{equation}
In the equation
\begin{equation}
11x^2-24xy+4y^2+20=0,
\end{equation}
$A=11$, $B=-24$, $C=4$, $D=0$, $E=0$, and $F=20$. We will rotate the xy-axis     through an angle where
\begin{equation}
\cot(2\theta)=\frac{11-4}{-24}=\frac{-7}{24}.
\end{equation}
We will replace x and y with 
\begin{equation}
x=X\cos\theta-Y\sin\theta 
y=X\sin\theta+Y\cos\theta.
\end{equation}
We use the multiple angle formulas for sine and cosine that come from the   addition formulas for sine and cosine
\begin{equation}
\cos(2\theta)=\cos^2(\theta)-\sin^2(\theta) and 
\sin(2\theta)=2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta).
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Environment `equation` is for one line equation.  For multi line equations you need to use amsath environments like `gather`, `align`, `multline`, `split` etc. Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Welcome! :) In your MWE you also have blank lines withing some of your `equation` environments. This will always fail as blank lines cannot appear in `equation` environments

Comment: @Au101 -- actually, blank lines aren't allowed in *any* math.  this is built into the tex engine, to allow a check (at every paragraph break) to ensure that math environments are completely self-contained, and not "run on".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for

We will replace x and y with

```
\begin{align*}
x=&X\cos\theta-Y\sin\theta \\
y=&X\sin\theta+Y\cos\theta.
\end{align*}
```

It is better to use `align` environment. If you want these equations to be numbered :

We will replace x and y with

```
\begin{align}
x=&X\cos\theta-Y\sin\theta \\
y=&X\sin\theta+Y\cos\theta.
\end{align}
```

(Edit) If you want only one of the equation to be numbered :

We will replace x and y with

```
\begin{align}
x=&X\cos\theta-Y\sin\theta \nonumber\\
y=&X\sin\theta+Y\cos\theta.
\end{align}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me transform my comment to the answer:

Environment `equation` is intended for one line equation. For multi line equations you should use `amsmath` or `mathtools` (which is extended version of `amsmath˙` package) environments like `gather`, `align`, `multline`, `split` to be numbered some of them. For details, read documentation for packages for `amsmath` or `mathtools`, or see [LaTeX/Mathematics](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics).

In example below is corrected your MWE, where is demonstrated use of `split` and `align` environment (from whole MWE is shown only part with use `split` and `align`)

[image]

Of course, select of appropriate `amsmath` environment is left to you.